# What should I use for coding C++ on a Mac and Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, macos

A group of students and I are making a C++ game, but they have Windows and I have a Mac is there something we can use to share code between the systems?

I know Eclipse will work but I get `Unresolved conclusion: <iostream>` as an error. If anyone can help with that it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to actually "share the code" with, I would recommend `git` using [github](http://www.github.com) as the remote location. Its free and easy to use.

If your question is about the code not working, make sure you [have `X11` configured properly](http://scottboms.com/2004/02/configurex11inmacosx/), and have the [Eclipse C++ plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR1-incubation-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz) installed.

And I would also recommend using `XCode` as your editor instead of Eclipse. It has a much better environment for C++, IMHO.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd recommend setting up a cross-platform build process using something like CMake (http://www.cmake.org). CMake in particular will generate platform-specific project files for you -- so your friends could be working in Visual Studio and you could be working in Eclipse or XCode, with no problems at all (of course, you'd have to write portable code... :))

As far as sharing code and version control goes, I agree with Jon that something like `git` is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

We build our Windows+Mac+Linux apps using Qt, which includes a nice build system (qmake) and cross-platform APIs (so the same code will run on all OS's) and an IDE (which I haven't used but I hear is okay).

With multiple developers you'll definitely want some sort of source-code-management system as well, git and svn are both good choices there.

Comment: This.  I've been using Qt for years to develop cross-platform apps and it's great.  *Some* platform-specific issues come up but they are rare.